# Keep user on same page when they click submit on form

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi the following code below is my comment form. I have included this file comments.php inside my blog posts. When the user clicks submit, they are taken to the blog page rather then kept on the blog article page they are viewing.

I have used this same code for different forms throughout my website, and those pages do not redirect, but rather they stay on the same page when the user clicks submit. Which is the correct way it should be.

I am wondering why this same code on the blog page is being redirected to blog category view when user clicks submit.

How can I prevent the redirection thanks.

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $commentErr = "";
    $name = $email = $comment = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "First Name is required";
    } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    }


    //email

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
    } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
    }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
    ?>

    <?php 
    if (count($_POST)>0) echo "<h2>Form Submitted! Thank you <b>$name $lname</b> 
    for your comment</h2>";
    ?>

    <hr>
    <h3 style=" margin-top: 50px; ">Leave a comment</h3>
    <h6><span class="error">* All fields required.</span></h6><br /><br />

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name*" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" required>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--Email-->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email address*" value="<?php echo $email;?>"required>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" style="margin-left: 17px;" name="comment" placeholder="Enter a comment*" rows="5" cols="40" required><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc3ZyUUAAAAAIT2Blrg4BseJK9KFc1Rx8VDVNs-"></div><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

    </div>
    <hr>
    </div>
    </div>

    </form>

    <?php

    //check if the form has been submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. */
    <?php include 'view/conn.php'; ?>

// Check connection
    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

// Escape user inputs for security
    $Fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
    $Message = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['comment']);

// attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (Name, Email, Comment, Approved) VALUES 
    ('$Fname', '$Email', '$Message', '0')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "<p>$Fname Your comment will appear once approved";
    } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

// close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>

    <?PHP
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $to = "email@email.com";
    $subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
    $headers = "From: $email\n";
    $message = "A visitor to your site has posted a comment on a blog post that requires approval.\n

    Email Address: $email";
    $user = "$email";
    $usersubject = "Thank You";
    $userheaders = "From: email@email.com\n";
    $usermessage = "Thank you for comment at www.oryanm.waiariki.net.nz Geyserland SBA.";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);
    ?>

    <?php
    echo "<h2>Comments</h2>";
    <?php include 'view/conn.php'; ?>

// Check connection
    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Approved=1 ORDER by id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<p><b>Comment by:</b> " . $row["Name"]. "</p>" . "<p>" . 
    $row["Comment"]. "</p> " . "<i><b>Posted:</b> " . $row["Posted"]. "</i><br>
    <hr>";
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: You'd be better off using Ajax for this.

Comment: would that be fairly long to implement into my already existing setup? Never used ajax before. I have website setup as flatfile php MVC

Comment: Use iframes then :)

Comment: I was thinking along those lines as well. Will give it a try.

Comment: That worked thanks for suggestion. But it has thrown off my styling now, but I can fix that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of php include, I used an iframe as a solution for this issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

pass one hidden field in your form

< input type="hidden" value="testRedirect">

and put redirect code on where you are redirect

and put redirect code on where you are redirect

if(isset($_REQUEST["hidden"]))

{

header('Location: http://www.example.com/your_form_view_page ');

exit;

}

Comment: how would I redirect to the current url they are on? As the comments is in a blog post, they could be on different urls.